# Passing an array to a function and pushing values to it using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sqlite

I am trying to populate Arrays dynamically from local storage SQLite Database Tables when a controller is loaded.

I have several Arrays defined as follows (small sample shown):

```
$scope.myArray1 = [];
$scope.myArray2 = [];
```

I then create an array with the table name/array name associateion e.g. *my_table_1* should be queried and then be written to *$scope.myArray1*. This looks as below (small sample shown):

```
$scope.tableArrayAssociation = [{
    tablename: "my_table_1",
    arrayname: "myArray1"
}, {
    tablename: "my_table_1",
    arrayname: "myArray2"
}];
```

To do this I have a function that calls a SQLite local storage database table and reads values from it.For my function I pass the table name to query and array to write the data to as function parameters.

I can query the required table no problem from the passed parameter, but when I try and insert into the array I get an error. Below is said function.

**onDeviceReady**

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    queryLocalStorageTablesAndBuildArrays($scope.tableArrayAssociation);
}
```

**Loop through each item, query the table and push to array.**

```
function queryLocalStorageTablesAndBuildArrays(tableArrayAssociation) {
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tableArrayAssociation.length; i++) {
        queryTable($scope.tableArrayAssociation[i].tablename, $scope.tableArrayAssociation[i].arrayname);
}

function queryTable(tableName, arrayName) {
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName + ''; // OK
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sql, [],
            (function (arrayName) {
                return function (tx, results) {
                    querySuccess(tx, results, arrayName);
                };
        })(arrayName), errorCB); // OK
    });
}

function querySuccess(tx, results, arrayName) {
    var len = results.rows.length; // OK

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        $scope[arrayName].push(results.rows.item(i)); // Not working here
        arrayName.push(results.rows.item(i)); // Also tried this, but arrayName.push is not a function error thrown
    }
}
```

*arrayName.push(...)* not working because I am just trying to push to a name (String) and not an actual Array. Showing a log for *$scope[arrayName]* shows it is an object but that the *push* didnt work - value = undefined.

Can anyone please suggest a solution to this? How do I assign the queried tables values to its corresponding array to populate values in my view?

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: The log shows that `$scope[arrayName]` is not an array? That is strange.. did u use it somewhere else?

Comment: No. No error message. Simply that the array length was undefined - so I assume its null/empty?

Comment: where did u try to get the array's length? could u show that since what u post seems nothing wrong to me.

Comment: Turns out it was working all along. Syntax error. Mis-spelt "length" as "lengh". Sorry and thanks for your time. Wouldnt have found it otherwise apart from checking the alert() again.